# Is there a way to prefill "to" parameter with multiple recipients on Facebook Graph.Api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, messaging

I have a checkbox list filled with random 10 of my facebook friends on my website. When I try to send a message to my selected friends, only the first of them appears on message dialog box.

```
        FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            name: 'MY Message',
            to: myArray //Array of Friend's IDs,
            link: 'http://www.mylink.com'
```

Does anybody know how to send a message with pre-filled recipient list?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/) `to` requires an array of names (and ids if available). Are you trying that and not having much luck?

Comment: It currently doesn't work and it's not planned. See [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/197423096996631) for more details.